# not defined error with Firefox and Malsup submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This works with Chrome and IE, but not Firefox, and I can't figure out why. Thanks in advance, this is taking me too long to figure out.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { //SEARCH FORM 
         $('#wrapper').delegate('#device_search','keyup', function(e) { 
            var searchquery = $('#device_search').val();
            localStorage.setItem("searchquery", searchquery);               
            if (searchquery) {
                $(".server_list_div").hide();     
                $(".search_results_div").show();       

                var options = { 
                    target:        '',
                    dataType:      'html',          
                    beforeSubmit:  showRequest_searchform,      
                    success:       showResponse_searchform
                }; 

                $("#search_form").ajaxSubmit(options); 


                function showRequest_searchform(formData, jqForm, options){         
                    return true; 
                }
                function showResponse_searchform(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){                     
                    $(".search_results_div").html(responseText);
                } 
                return false;
            } else {
                $(".scroll_div").show(); 
                $(".scroll_div_results").hide(); 
            }
         });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Try declaring the function before the `option` declaration. It's a long shot, but it might work...

Comment: I think you need to relocate where you're declaring the function showRequest_searchform. Can you move that out of your if statement and under the ready?

Comment: Yup that was it.  Knew it was something simple.  Thanks @jonmrich

Comment: Cool. I just added it as an answer in case anyone else comes across this in search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your functions out of the `if` statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function showRequest_searchform(formData, jqForm, options){         
                    return true; 
                }
                function showResponse_searchform(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){                     
                    $(".search_results_div").html(responseText);
                } 
                return false;
                 //SEARCH FORM 
         $('#wrapper').delegate('#device_search','keyup', function(e) { 
            var searchquery = $('#device_search').val();
            localStorage.setItem("searchquery", searchquery);               
            if (searchquery) {
                $(".server_list_div").hide();     
                $(".search_results_div").show();       

                var options = { 
                    target:        '',
                    dataType:      'html',          
                    beforeSubmit:  showRequest_searchform,      
                    success:       showResponse_searchform
                }; 

                $("#search_form").ajaxSubmit(options); 



            } else {
                $(".scroll_div").show(); 
                $(".scroll_div_results").hide(); 
            }
         });
    });
```

Comment: OP's code should work. As mentioned it works in Chrome. This is called _hoisting_

Answer (score 1):

You came across an old [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=944855) in FF. Functions inside `if` block are not [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)